# How to display only shell variables (not functions)

Tags: bash, variable, function

How can I display a list of shell variables in Bash, not including functions, which often clutter the output, because of the many related to completion?

I have examined `declare`, and it has an option for limiting the output to functions (`declare -f`), but not for limiting the output to "plain" shell variables?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The command `compgen -v` will display a list of names of shell variables in the current `bash` shell session.  Also, `declare -p`, which lists  the attributes and values of all variables in a form that is (almost always) suitable for shell input, does not list functions.

Comment: Thank you. What I would have anticipated the most, is the output of `declare` without functions, i.e. just name/value pairs. Are functions also considered variables, or why does `declare` include them?

Comment: @Shuzheng The `bash` shell stores functions as a special type of variable. Other shells do not do that.

Comment: By *special type of variable* - what do you mean? Will you elaborate, although off-topic for the question? I see that functions and variables can exist with the same name, i.e. `f() { echo foo; }; f=bar`

Comment: @Shuzheng The shell still keeps an illusion of a separate name-space for variables and functions (which it _must_ do).  If you _export_ a function (`export -f f`) and use `printenv`, you would see `BASH_FUNC_f%%` as the name.

Comment: Why must it do that? Why export a function? Child processes are not able to call it, anyway?

Comment: @Shuzheng Must do what? I the child process is a `bash` shell, it can call the exported function. But you are getting side-tracked now. Your follow-up question was about the names of functions. I gave you an example that showed that `bash` stores functions as variables. I used an exported function as an example so that I could use the external utility `printenv` to view its name. If I had used built-in utilities, `bash` would have made it look like the function was just called `f`.

Comment: I see, thanks. What i meant was "*The shell still keeps an illusion of a separate name-space for variables and functions (which it must do)*". What do you mean here?

Comment: @Shuzheng Exactly what I wrote. If you ask `bash` about what the currently defined functions are, it will list these for you using the names you have given them, even if these names seems to be the same as some variables' names. I.e., it maintains the illusion of separate name spaces for variables and functions, even though it actually stores functions as "special variables".  If you have further questions about this particular topic, I suggest that you ask a separate question.